# How do we get this Imperial Wit to finish?

Tags: fermentation

We brewed an imperial wit that wound up 1.070 OG. I used a 1.5L starter with Wyeast 3944, but I likely still underpitched. After a week fermenting at 68F/20C, gravity is still 1.035 and it's pretty sweet. Should I re-pitch with the same yeast to get it to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try giving the fermenter a good shake to stir up the yeast and restart the fermentation.

To get my barely wines to ferment completely I need to shake the fermenter a couple of times. I wait until the fermentation has slowed right down and then shake the fermenter to stir up the yeast and trub in the bottom. This helps restart the fermentation.

Using this method I can get a barley wine with a 1.100+ OG down to around 1.030 in around two weeks, without the need to re-pitch yeast.

Comment: Sure enough, shaking the fermenter was all that was needed. Fermentation was so vigorous after shaking I had to replace the airlock with a blowoff tube. The wit finished at 1.010!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already going with a Belgian strain it might be best to re-pitch something like The Yeast Bay's [Dry Belgian Ale](http://www.theyeastbay.com/brewers-yeast-products/dry-belgian-ale), and in the meantime give the fermentor a swirl. Assuming you had a bit of wheat/oats in the recipe it should hopefully not dry out *too* much.